# Unable to send request.data and get api response?

Tags: reactjs, axios

**Requesting with Axios to fetch data from API**

```
export const getReports = async (url, obj) => {
    return new Promise(
        async (resolve, reject) => {
            try {
                const data = await axios.request(
                    {
                        method: 'get',
                        url: BASE_URL+url,
                        headers: {

                            'Authorization':  `Bearer ${await getAccessToken()}`
                        },
                        data: {date_to:'2019-11-05',date_from:'2019-11-05',c_name:'1'}
                    }
                );
                resolve(data);
            } catch (e) {
                reject(e)
            }
        }
    )
};
```

Getting error and not able to receive request.data on the backend...

**Working on Postman**

in Body
 - date_to:'2019-11-05'
 -date_from:'2019-11-05'
 -c_name:'1'

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: have you checked in your chorme developer tools in network what are you sending?
Is it the same that in postman?

Answer (score 0):

If you have request type of GET axios doesn't use the data field.

(From the docs)

```
  // `data` is the data to be sent as the request body
  // Only applicable for request methods 'PUT', 'POST', and 'PATCH'
  // When no `transformRequest` is set, must be of one of the following types:
  // - string, plain object, ArrayBuffer, ArrayBufferView, URLSearchParams
  // - Browser only: FormData, File, Blob
  // - Node only: Stream, Buffer
  data: {
    firstName: 'Fred'
  },
```

The data field is for POST, PUT, PATCH, etc. You could try using query params or change the type of the request.

Here is about query params from the docs

```
  // `params` are the URL parameters to be sent with the request
  // Must be a plain object or a URLSearchParams object
  params: {
    ID: 12345
  }
```

So this would appear as url.com?ID=12345

Then you can parse them from the backend. This is also the HTTP standard and you shouldn't try sending body data with GET request.